# WordPress .htaccess ReWrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I am trying to change all instances of ?category=[name], with "info" in my urls. In my .htaccess, I tried putting this after the RewriteRule regarding the index (within the BEGIN WordPress and END WordPres comments):

```
RewriteRule ^info$ ?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

So basically if we have www.example.com/bill/?category=test, it should instead be www.example.com/bill/info, or better yet, just replacing it with nothing would be better, so www.example.com/bill. Either way works.

I do need to get that category variable, though. If this would cause errors, then something like www.example.com/bill/test would be acceptable, as long as that still lets me grab the category variable in php.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the .htaccess file is not going to do what you want with regards to this working as a variable in WordPress. However, there is the WordPress rewrite system (the one that handles the permalinks among other things). This will allow you to use a URL like `https://www.example.com/bill/test` and assign "test" to a variable.

I also recommend adding the Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin (https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/rewrite-rules-inspector) as it will help you to understand better what is going on and to verify that your functions are taking effect.

This first thing you will need to do is register a new query variable. You can add more than one. They would just add to the URL like `/bill/<billCategory>/<billSomething>`. You need to make sure you stay away from names that might conflict. Unfortunately, these are not well documented.

```
function add_bill_arguments( $public_query_vars )
{
    $public_query_vars[] = 'billCategory';
    return $public_query_vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_bill_arguments');
```

Next you will have to add your rewrite rule. This will tell WordPress to sort of "stop" at `/bill/` and assign all that follows to the query vars you set up.

```
function bill_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( '^bill/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=bill&billCategory=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_action('init', 'bill_rewrite');
```

Now that you have those in place, you can get to your variable like so...

```
global $wp_query;

if( is_page( 'bill' ) )
{
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['billCategory'] ) )
        $billCategory = $wp_query->query_vars['billCategory'];

    echo $billCategory;
}
```

Once you've added your rewrite(s), you need to flush the rewrite rules. The easiest way to do that is by going in to the admin and visiting Settings->Permalinks. Then click on the Save button. When the page reloads, do it again. Once in a while the rewrites get stuck. If you installed the plugin I mentioned above, you can check to make sure they are in there.

Hopefully that will help get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to leave me such a detailed answer! I don't understand your second code blurb, regarding add_rewrite_rule. Why are you specifying index.php? There is no index.php in my url. I also don't think I need the pagename variable, as the page using this variable is actually using a custom single .php template.

Comment: Everything in WordPress goes through the <document_root>/index.php. That is why it is specified in the redirect. You will need it to work this way if you still want WP loading everything else. You should also separate your code from your layout. If you are putting functionality like that in the template you will not be able to switch templates and still use your functionality. Consider running your code through a `shortcode` or template override.